# What is the opposite of organic (food)?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The word *inorganic* is patently inappropriate for describing food, even if that food wasn't produced in a manner consistent with *organic farming*. [Wikipedia points this out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_food#Meaning_and_origin_of_the_term), but doesn't really offer an alternative. While the phrase *food produced through chemical farming* may leave some people with a bad taste in their mouth, I doubt it carries the same connotation as *food that is not organic food*. Is there a better word to use here?

Comment: The term *organic food* has been introduced to distinguish from that produced with the use of chemical or other growth promoters/ 'bio-cides', etc. As such you cannot have an antonym for the term *organic food*.

Comment: @Kris I don't understand why such a term precludes the existence of its antonym; even so, though, if your point is about the definition of *antonym*, can you come up with a word that describes *the relative complement of organic food in food* (set theory)?

Comment: Take a look also at the interesting discussion on "Word for “cinema with a single screen” http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85475/word-for-cinema-with-a-single-screen/85486#85486

Comment: Pesticidal - but it wouldn't make a great advertisement for the product.

Comment: What is the context for the word you want to use? If it's advertising, it needs a different answer from describing such food in an academic paper.

Comment: @AndrewLeach no specific context, but pure curiosity.

Comment: Regarding the above sentence, "The term organic food has been introduced to distinguish from that produced with the use of **chemical** or other growth promoters...." Even food labeled as USDA approved organic has been treated with approved organic **chemicals**, such as copper sulfate, pyrethrum, and others. Many of these organic pesticides and herbicides are just as dangerous as their synthetic counterparts for human consumption, and often even more so. Using the word **chemical** as though it applies only to conventionally produced food is at best misleading, and at worst disingenuous.

Comment: @MichelleMackenzie I can't speak for Kris, but as the Wikipedia article says, the author who coined the term *organic* contrasted it with what he called *chemical farming*. Had I found that term adequate I wouldn't have needed to ask this question. On the other hand it's pretty hard to describe exactly what is wrong with applying the term *inorganic* to food without talking about chemistry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most often, "conventional" is used as a retronym for "not organic."

It's not great, and a better one may gain acceptance; be patient: these things take time.

Comment: [Here](http://www.coextra.eu/glossary/word672.html) are a [couple of links](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22conventional+farming%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks) to strengthen your case. Other terms that I came across in my cursory search were _sustainable_ and _traditional_ farming.

Comment: @coleopterist, I don't agree that *sustainable* is equivalent to *organic*. See this discussion about the distinction between *organic* and *sustainable*: http://www.sustainabletable.org/issues/organic/

Answer (score 10):

For product labels, the USDA uses *non-organic* to contrast with *organic*. See these links:

> http://blogs.usda.gov/2012/03/22/organic-101-what-the-usda-organic-label-means/

> http://www.greenerchoices.org/eco-labels/label.cfm?LabelID=151

As Jeffiekins says in his answer, for the farming method used to produce the food or textile, the terms the USDA and others use are usually *organic* vs. *conventional*:

> http://www.nal.usda.gov/afsic/nsfc/39.htm

> https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/organic-food/art-20043880